# XSLT grouping by node value with each siblings

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I started learning xslt quite recently and I was faced with the following task.

There are many similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them considers the case when you need to put a value in a lower case

This my input XML. I try to put meltNum value into <chem> node.

```
<meltChem>
   <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
   <chem>
      <elemCode>1</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
      <elemCode>2</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
      <elemCode>3</elemCode>
      <value>0.0002</value>
   </chem>
   </meltChem>
   <meltChem>
   <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
   <chem>
      <elemCode>4</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
      <elemCode>5</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
   </chem>
</meltChem>
```

I don't know how to get xml like this:

```
<meltChem>
   <chem>
   <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>1</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
   <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>2</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
   <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>3</elemCode>
      <value>0.0002</value>
   </chem>
</meltChem>
<meltChem>
   <chem>
   <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
      <elemCode>4</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
   </chem>
   <chem>
   <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
      <elemCode>5</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
   </chem>
</meltChem>
```

I'm trying to use some stack overflow solution with same problem, but I'am getting duplication of nodes.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//docChem/meltChem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('a', meltNum)[1])]">
    <meltNum>
    <xsl:value-of select="meltNum"/>
    </meltNum>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('a', meltNum)">
    <elemCode>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//elemCode"/>
    </elemCode>
    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

and then i got

```
 <meltNum>В301996</meltNum>
        <elemCode>
          <elemCode>1</elemCode>
          <elemCode>2</elemCode>
          <elemCode>3</elemCode>
          <elemCode>4</elemCode>
          <elemCode>5</elemCode>
        </elemCode>
        <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
        <elemCode>
          <elemCode>1</elemCode>
          <elemCode>2</elemCode>
          <elemCode>3</elemCode>
          <elemCode>4</elemCode>
          <elemCode>5</elemCode>
        </elemCode>
```

Comment: You XML is not **well-formed**. It is missing a root node. Please fix it.

Comment: *"none of them considers the case when you need to put a value in a lower case"* Where exactly do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

I added a root element to make XML well-formed.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <meltChem>
        <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
        <chem>
            <elemCode>1</elemCode>
            <value>0.052</value>
        </chem>
        <chem>
            <elemCode>2</elemCode>
            <value>0.003</value>
        </chem>
        <chem>
            <elemCode>3</elemCode>
            <value>0.0002</value>
        </chem>
    </meltChem>
    <meltChem>
        <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
        <chem>
            <elemCode>4</elemCode>
            <value>0.052</value>
        </chem>
        <chem>
            <elemCode>5</elemCode>
            <value>0.003</value>
        </chem>
    </meltChem>
</root>
```

**XSLT #1**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chem">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--<xsl:copy-of select="../meltNum"/>-->
            <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::meltNum"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--remove meltNum element-->
    <xsl:template match="meltNum"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT #2**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="meltChem">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:variable name="meltNum">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="meltNum"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:for-each select="chem">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$meltNum"/>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<root>
  <meltChem>
    <chem>
      <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>1</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
    </chem>
    <chem>
      <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>2</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
    </chem>
    <chem>
      <meltNum>301996</meltNum>
      <elemCode>3</elemCode>
      <value>0.0002</value>
    </chem>
  </meltChem>
  <meltChem>
    <chem>
      <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
      <elemCode>4</elemCode>
      <value>0.052</value>
    </chem>
    <chem>
      <meltNum>99999</meltNum>
      <elemCode>5</elemCode>
      <value>0.003</value>
    </chem>
  </meltChem>
</root>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. The repeated lookup along the preceding-sibling axis wastes time and CPU cycles.  The common value should be located once at the parent level and put in a variable.

Comment: #2 is close to how I would do it - except I would do simply `<xsl:variable name="meltNum" select="meltNum" />`. You are unnecessarily creating a separate tree fragment containing a copy of the node, instead of just pointing at the original one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks you a lot, your solution was wery helpful for me.